# Is there any way of retrieving phase information with only access to real part of successive FFT frames?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, phase

Due to a limitation of the WebAudio specification the FFT available in JavaScript only makes available the real part (1st half) of the calculated frequency data. Is there any way of recreating the phase information (and subsequently improving interpolation of peak frequencies) using the fluctuations in bin amplitude between frames?

Comment: What is your objective with the processing? Having the phase information won't improve the frequency precision (if by that you mean the frequency bin values). Looking at the specs it seems the sample is windowed as well, then the frequency bin magnitudes are smoothed.

Comment: http://blogs.zynaptiq.com/bernsee/pitch-shifting-using-the-ft/ section 3 hints at being able to reconstruct true frequency of a peek using phase information.

Comment: also of the interpolation algorithms mentioned in http://dspguru.com/dsp/howtos/how-to-interpolate-fft-peak the most accurate one utilises both real and imaginary information.

Comment: ahhh I see, that is clever.

Comment: The answer is probably "yes" if you allow all sorts of expensive computations. Basically, if you have sufficient overlap between frames, you should always be able to find (a priori) some pairs of frames that will be roughly 90° out of phase. These pairs do not depend on the data, but will be different for each bin. For example, if the overlap is 3/4 of the window length, the second bin should show a ~90° rotation from frame to frame. (3/4 will not give you anything meaningful for bins with odd bin indices, though; it's just an example.)

Comment: Or maybe you can run the signal through a filter that rotates all phases by 90°, and compute another FFT on the rotated data...

Comment: So I spent the day experimenting in JavaScript by averaging the variation between successive values of just the real part of an FFT bin containing the peek of a test tone (pure sine) and there was undoubtedly some correlation between the magnitude of the variation (in the floating point values) to the offset of the tone frequency from the central bin frequency. However there is also noise in non-adjacent bins - which in the case of multiple peeks may bury the information... Will investigate further if I can't get the resolution needed by simpler means.

Comment: are you sure it's giving you the real part and not the magnitude of the DFT? That would sound much much more likely to be in demand by web developers!

Comment: http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#fourier-transform specifies the same complex FFT definition as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Definition_and_speed but explicitly defines k=0,...,N/2-1 instead of k=0,...,N-1

Comment: webaudio isn't returning the real part of the complex transform, but the log magnitude of the transform.  It's returning n/2 points because the other half is symmetric in magnitude (given the real-only audio input) and thus redundant.  Thus there is no way to recover the phase.

Comment: @hotpaw2 where is the imaginary part of the audio input meant to come from for the time domain signal?

Comment: @norlesh : Complete frequency data has both magnitude and phase information.  The real and imaginary components together form a 2D vector, with the angle of that vector representing the phase of each sinusoidal basis component in the signal.  Thus, the imaginary component won't be zero unless the phase is zero (which is only true for mirror symmetric real input vectors).

Comment: A "normal" fft produces N complex results.  With the complex vector containing half real and half imaginary as components.  Half of those halves are symmetric and thus redundant for real input (that half of an FFT result is computed so that a "complete" fft can take complex inputs with non-zero imaginary components).  So webaudio is only providing 1/4th as much data as a full complex fft result, not one-half.  Thus the loss of phase information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

webaudio isn't returning the real part of the complex FFT transform, but just the log magnitude of the FFT result.  From just this result alone, of the fluctuations between the results of multiple frames, you can't retrieve the phase information.

However, if you can get at the input data and decompose this input vector into a symmetric vector plus an anti-symmetric vector, the magnitude of the FFT of the symmetric vector will be equivalent to scaled real components of the FFT of the original input vector, and the magnitude of the FFT of the anti-symmetric vector will be equal scaled imaginary components of the FFT of the original input vector.  Thus, the decomposition plus 2 magnitude-only FFTs will allow you to determine both the magnitude and phase of the FFT components.

```
v_even = v + v_reversed
v_odd  = v - v_reversed
```

Comment: Doh! it took me about 10 passes at reading the mathematics in the 
WebAudio FFT section before I finally found where the complex data is converted to magnitude during the smoothing... after a full FFT has been performed (GRRR!!!)